# How to add HashMaps with custom objects to an ArrayList

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I have a problem when adding HashMaps with custom objects to an ArrayList. Here you are the HashMaps definitions:

```
static Map<Long, Supermarket> supermarkets = new HashMap<Long, Supermarket>();
static Map<Long, Product> products = new HashMap<Long, Product>();
```

And this is the ArrayList definition:

```
static ArrayList<HashMap> supemarketsAndProducts = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
```

I also tried with a List with same results.
**Product** is a class which creates product objects.
**Supermarket** is the class which creates supermarkets objects.

The problem is when adding elements to de ArrayList. I am trying on this way:

```
supemarketsAndProducts.add(supermarkets);
supemarketsAndProducts.add(products);
```

I need an structure made of those hashmaps (supermarkets and products) because I need this class returning both hashmaps structures. What am I doing wrong? Any solution/workaround to return the hashmaps I need?

Thanks and regards.

Edited: Here you are the full code (but it is too long: it is a customized SAX parser which is called from another class, and variables names are in spanish).

```
package parsers;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.*;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class LectorXML extends DefaultHandler {

  static Map<Long, Supermercado> supermercados = new HashMap<Long, Supermercado>();
  static Map<Long, Producto> productos = new HashMap<Long, Producto>();
  static List<Map> supermercadosYproductos = new ArrayList<Map>();
  static Long numeroSupermercado = 0L;
  static Long numeroProducto = 0L;

  private final XMLReader xr;
  boolean bfname = false;
  boolean blname = false;
  boolean bnname = false;
  boolean bsalary = false;
  boolean bs_id = false;
  boolean bnombre = false;
  boolean bdireccion = false;
  boolean bpoblacion = false;
  boolean bprovincia = false;
  boolean blongitud = false;
  boolean blatitud = false;
  boolean bfavorito = false;
  boolean btelefono = false;
  boolean bp_id = false;
  boolean bcodigobarras = false;
  boolean bnombrep = false;
  boolean bfabricante = false;
  boolean bcategoria_1 = false;
  boolean bcategoria_2 = false;
  boolean bcategoria_3 = false;
  boolean bprecio_1 = false;
  boolean bfecha_1 = false;
  boolean bprecio_2 = false;
  boolean bfecha_2 = false;
  boolean bsupermercado = false;
  boolean bdireccion_supermercado = false;
  boolean bpoblacion_supermercado = false;
  boolean bcomprar = false;

  public LectorXML() throws SAXException {
    xr = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    xr.setContentHandler(this);
    xr.setErrorHandler(this);
  }

  public void leer(final String archivoXML)
          throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SAXException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivoXML);
    xr.parse(new InputSource(fr));
  }

//  @Override
//  public void startDocument() {
//    System.out.println("Comienzo del Documento XML");
//  }
//  @Override
//  public void endDocument() {
//    System.out.println("Final del Documento XML");
//  }
  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String name,
          String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
//    System.out.println("tElemento: " + name);
//          System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
//            System.out.println("qName: ------  " + qName + " ---------");
//            System.out.println("ttAtributo: "
//                    + attributes.getLocalName(i) + " = " + attributes.getValue(i));
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("s_id")) {
        bs_id = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("nombre")) {
//              System.out.println("Nombre del supermercado: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bnombre = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("direccion")) {
//              System.out.println("Dirección del supermercado: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bdireccion = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("poblacion")) {
//              System.out.println("Población del supermercado: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bpoblacion = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("provincia")) {
//              System.out.println("Provincia del supermercado: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bprovincia = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("longitud")) {
//              System.out.println("Longitud del supermercado: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        blongitud = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("latitud")) {
//              System.out.println("Latitud del supermercado: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        blatitud = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("favorito")) {
//              System.out.println("¿Supermercado favorito?: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bfavorito = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("telefono")) {
//              System.out.println("Teléfono del supermercado: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        btelefono = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("p_id")) {
//              System.out.println("Id del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bp_id = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("codigobarras")) {
//              System.out.println("Código de barras del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bcodigobarras = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("nombrep")) {
//              System.out.println("Nombre del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bnombrep = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("fabricante")) {
//              System.out.println("Fabricante del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bfabricante = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("categoria_1")) {
//              System.out.println("Categoría del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bcategoria_1 = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("categoria_2")) {
//              System.out.println("Categoría 2 del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bcategoria_2 = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("categoria_3")) {
//              System.out.println("Categoría 3 del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bcategoria_3 = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("precio_1")) {
//              System.out.println("Precio del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bprecio_1 = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("fecha_1")) {
//              System.out.println("Fecha del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bfecha_1 = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("precio_2")) {
//              System.out.println("Precio 2 del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bprecio_2 = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("fecha_2")) {
//              System.out.println("Fecha 2 del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bfecha_2 = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("supermercado")) {
//              System.out.println("Nombre del supermercado del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bsupermercado = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("direccion_supermercado")) {
//              System.out.println("Dirección del supermercado del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bdireccion_supermercado = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("poblacion_supermercado")) {
//              System.out.println(" Población del supermercado del producto: " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bpoblacion_supermercado = true;
      }
      if (attributes.getValue(i).equalsIgnoreCase("comprar")) {
//              System.out.println(" Comprar el producto? " + attributes.getValue(i));
        bfavorito = true;
      }
    }
  }

//  @Override
//  public void endElement(String uri, String name,
//          String qName) throws SAXException {
//    System.out.println("tFin Elemento: " + name);
//  }
  @Override
  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
          throws SAXException {
//    System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));

    Supermercado supermercado = new Supermercado();
    Producto producto = new Producto();

    if (bs_id) {
      String idSupermercado = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Id del supermercado: " + idSupermercado);
      bs_id = false;
      supermercado.supermercadoId = Long.parseLong(idSupermercado);
    }
    if (bnombre) {
      String nombreSupermercado = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Nombre del supermercado: " + nombreSupermercado);
      bnombre = false;
      supermercado.nombre = nombreSupermercado;
    }
    if (bdireccion) {
      String direccionSupermercado = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Dirección del supermercado: " + direccionSupermercado);
      bdireccion = false;
      supermercado.direccion = direccionSupermercado;
    }
    if (bpoblacion) {
      String poblacionSupermercado = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Población del supermercado: " + poblacionSupermercado);
      bpoblacion = false;
      if (poblacionSupermercado.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        supermercado.poblacion = null;
      else supermercado.poblacion = poblacionSupermercado;
    }
    if (bprovincia) {
      String provinciaSupermercado = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Provincia del supermercado: " + provinciaSupermercado);
      bprovincia = false;
      supermercado.provincia = provinciaSupermercado;
    }
    if (blongitud) {
      String longitudSupermercado = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Longitud del supermercado: " + longitudSupermercado);
      blongitud = false;
      if (longitudSupermercado.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        supermercado.longitud = null;
      else supermercado.longitud = Double.parseDouble(longitudSupermercado);
    }
    if (blatitud) {
      String latitudSupermercado = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Latitud del supermercado: " + latitudSupermercado);
      blatitud = false;
      if (latitudSupermercado.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        supermercado.latitud = null;
      else supermercado.latitud = Double.parseDouble(latitudSupermercado);
    }
    if (bfavorito) {
      String supermercadoFavorito = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Supermercado favorito? " + supermercadoFavorito);
      bfavorito = false;
      if (supermercadoFavorito.equals("0")) {
        supermercado.favorito = false;
      } else if (supermercadoFavorito.equals("1")) {
        supermercado.favorito = true;
      }
    }
    if (btelefono) {
      String telefonoSupermercado = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Teléfono del supermercado: " + telefonoSupermercado);
      btelefono = false;
      if (telefonoSupermercado.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        supermercado.telefono = null;
      else supermercado.telefono = telefonoSupermercado;
    }
    if (bp_id) {
      String idProducto = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Id del producto: " + idProducto);
      bp_id = false;
      producto.productoId = Long.parseLong(idProducto);
    }
    if (bcodigobarras) {
      String codigoBarras = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Código de barras del producto: " + codigoBarras);
      bcodigobarras = false;
      if (codigoBarras.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        producto.codigobarras = null;
      else producto.codigobarras = codigoBarras;
    }
    if (bnombrep) {
      String nombreProducto = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Nombre del producto: " + nombreProducto);
      bnombrep = false;
      producto.nombre = nombreProducto;
    }
    if (bfabricante) {
      String fabricanteProducto = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Fabricante del producto: " + fabricanteProducto);
      bfabricante = false;
      if (fabricanteProducto.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        producto.fabricante = null;
      else producto.fabricante = fabricanteProducto;
    }
    if (bcategoria_1) {
      String categoria1 = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Categoría del producto: " + categoria1);
      bcategoria_1 = false;
      producto.categoria_1 = categoria1;
    }
    if (bcategoria_2) {
      String categoria2 = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Categoría 2 del producto: " + categoria2);
      bcategoria_2 = false;
      if (categoria2.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        producto.categoria_2 = null;
      else producto.categoria_2 = categoria2;
    }
    if (bcategoria_3) {
      String categoria3 = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Categoría 3 del producto: " + categoria3);
      bcategoria_3 = false;
      if (categoria3.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        producto.categoria_3 = null;
      else producto.categoria_3 = categoria3;
    }
    if (bprecio_1) {
      String precio1 = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Precio del producto: " + precio1);
      bprecio_1 = false;
      if (precio1.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        producto.precio_1 = null;
      else producto.precio_1 = Double.parseDouble(precio1);
    }
    if (bfecha_1) {
      String fecha1 = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Fecha del producto: " + fecha1);
      bfecha_1 = false;
      if (fecha1.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        producto.fecha_1 = null;
      else producto.fecha_1 = ConvertirFecha.conversion(fecha1);
    }
    if (bprecio_2) {
      String precio2 = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Precio 2 del producto: " + precio2);
      bprecio_2 = false;
      if (precio2.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        producto.precio_2 = null;
      else producto.precio_2 = Double.parseDouble(precio2);
    }
    if (bfecha_2) {
      String fecha2 = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Fecha 2 del producto: " + fecha2);
      bfecha_2 = false;
      if (fecha2.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        producto.fecha_2 = null;
      else producto.fecha_2 = ConvertirFecha.conversion(fecha2);
    }
    if (bsupermercado) {
      String nombreSupermercadoProducto = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Nombre del supermercado del producto: " + nombreSupermercadoProducto);
      bsupermercado = false;
      producto.supermercado = nombreSupermercadoProducto;
    }
    if (bdireccion_supermercado) {
      String direccionSupermercadoProducto = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Dirección del supermercado del producto: " + direccionSupermercadoProducto);
      bdireccion_supermercado = false;
      producto.direccion_supermercado = direccionSupermercadoProducto;
    }
    if (bpoblacion_supermercado) {
      String poblacionSupermercadoProducto = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println("Población del supermercado del producto: " + poblacionSupermercadoProducto);
      bpoblacion_supermercado = false;
      if (poblacionSupermercadoProducto.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        producto.poblacion_supermercado = null;
      else producto.poblacion_supermercado = poblacionSupermercadoProducto;
    }
    if (bcomprar) {
      String comprarProducto = new String(ch, start, length);
      System.out.println(" Comprar el producto? " + comprarProducto);
      bcomprar = false;
      if (comprarProducto.equals("0")) {
        producto.comprar = false;
      } else if (comprarProducto.equals("1")) {
        producto.comprar = true;
      }
    }
    if (supermercado.supermercadoId != null)
      supermercados.put(numeroSupermercado, supermercado);
    if (producto.productoId != null)
      productos.put(numeroProducto, producto);
  }
  supermercadosYproductos.add(supermercados);
  supermercadosYproductos.add(productos);
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? Please specify clearly. And please post `real code`.

Comment: remove the Generics <HashMap> from the supermarketsAndproducts. so your list will be generic accepting both the hashmaps!

Comment: Could you not return an Object of type `SupermarketStock` or similar, that combines a `Supermarket` with some `Products`?

Comment: @RohitJain that's the real code (after translating variables names from spanish to english).

Comment: @madhairsilence problem perssits :(

Comment: @Edd yes, I could create a new class wich is made of Product and Supermarket objects. I will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I resolved the issue on my own.
The definition was ok (original code, no translations for variables for not wasting more time haha):

```
static List<Map> supermercadosYproductos = new ArrayList<Map>();
```

The problem was that I was trying to save products and supermarkets in the wrong place: it should be in my `public List<Map> leer(final String archivoXML)` method in this way:

```
if (!supermercadosYproductos.isEmpty()) {
  supermercadosYproductos.add(supermercados);
  supermercadosYproductos.add(productos);
  return supermercadosYproductos;
}
else return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use wildcards to cover the fact that you are adding disparate maps into the list:

```
static List<Map<Long, ?>> supemarketsAndProducts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Of course, when you retrieve an object from this list, you won't have a static type for it. That would be impossible to achieve. You'll need to perform an unchecked cast, and there goes your type safety.

Comment: It doesn'w tork on jdk1.6, just on 1.7. Any idea for 1.6? Thanks.

Comment: Just copy the type parameters from the left-hand side into the right-hand side.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get: `<identifier> expected` `package supemarketsAndProducts does not exist` when i try to save it in this way `supemarketsAndProducts.add(0L, supermarkets);`. The declaration is `static List<Map<Long, ?>> supemarketsAndProducts = new ArrayList<Map<Long, ?>>();`